# NSSegmentedControl remove blue highlight - just make it pressing state

Tags: objective-c, macos

How to remove blue highlight from NSSegmentedControl (which is currently in NSToolBar as item) so I make it work like NSPopupButton with pressed state. Thanks.

Comment: Do you want it to keep working (switching) but not indicating visually which segment is current?

Comment: It's called a "focus ring", and it can be turned off in IB.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for activity guys. I should start my question from I am new to macOS development, so it was easy - just to change a style of NSSegmentedControl.